# Angular 8 - form validation is not working properly

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, maxlength, formgroups

```html
<mat-form-field class="input-label-add">
  <input matInput placeholder="Registration **" formControlName="registration">
  <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').hasError('maxlength')">registration cannot exceed 8 characters</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').errors">registration or surname is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
this.addLockerForm =  this.formBuilder.group({
    locker_serial_number: [null, Validators.required],
    customer_surname: [null],
    registration: [null, Validators.maxLength(10)],
    mobile: [null],
    email: [null],
    date_in: [null, Validators.required],
    date_out: [null, Validators.required], 
  },
  { validator: [this.validateCustomerDetails, this.validateCustomerContact] });
```

addLockerForm.get('registration').hasError('maxlength') stays false all the time

Comment: Please add the component .ts code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this ?

```
addLockerForm.get('registration').errors.maxlength
```

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions

**EDIT 1**

You don't need to use `.errors`.

Please update your code like this :

```html
<mat-form-field class="input-label-add">
  <input matInput placeholder="Registration **" formControlName="registration">
  <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').hasError('maxlength')">registration cannot exceed 8 characters</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').hasError('required')">registration or surname is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
registration: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(8)]],
```

Comment: when I start typing something in the input field it's giving me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxlength' of null at Object.eval"

Comment: if you want use errors.maxlength, don't forget the "safe operator" `errors?.maxlength`

Comment: @Emilien Yes, it does now after I modified the custom validation method. Thank you.

Comment: @IvilinStoyanov If your solution come from StackOverflow, please make an answer as "resolved". Otherwise, you can edit your post adding your solution :)

Comment: @Emilien Okay :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my custom validation method where I remove any errors for the following form control.
I forgot about this method. Thank you all for the help.

```
validateCustomerDetails(g: FormGroup) {
if ((isNullOrUndefined(g.get('registration').value) || g.get('registration').value == "") &&
  (isNullOrUndefined(g.get('customer_surname').value) || g.get('customer_surname').value == "")) {
  g.controls['registration'].setErrors({ 'empty': true });
  g.controls['customer_surname'].setErrors({ 'empty': true });
}
else {
  g.controls['registration'].setErrors(null);
  g.controls['customer_surname'].setErrors(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  *ngIf="addLockerForm.controls?.registration?.invalid && addLockerForm.controls?.registration?.touched"

this.addLockerForm = formbuilder.group({
     registration: [
       "",
       [
         Validators.required,
         Validators.minLength(4),
         Validators.maxLength(8),
         Validators.pattern(Your Pattern)
       ]
     ]  
  }
```

If U are Using FormBuilder And Validator
Use FormBuilder In Your Ts File

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
<mat-form-field class="input-label-add">
   <input matInput placeholder="Registration **" formControlName="registration">
   <div *ngIf="registration.errors">
      <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').errors.maxlength">
         registration cannot exceed 8 characters</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="addLockerForm.get('registration').errors.required">registration or surname is required</mat-error>
   </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Akhil, if you want use errors.maxlength, don't forget the "safe operator" `errors?.maxlength`